# How do I generate a candlestick chart from Morningstar data using matplotlib and mpl_finance?

Tags: python, matplotlib, candlestick-chart

I wantt o import data from morningstar and generate a candlestick chart.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import mpl_finance as mpf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


AAPL = web.DataReader('AAPL', 'morningstar', start = '1/1/2000',end =  '5/29/2018')


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (8,5))
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
mpf.candlestick_ohlc(ax, AAPL, width = 0.6, colorup = 'b', colordown = 'r', alpha = 0.75)
ax.xaxis_date()
ax.autoscale_view()
ax.xaxis.grid(True, 'major')
ax.grid(True)
```

I am getting an error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can try converting the data to floats: `AAPL.astype(float)`, looks like there may be strings in there instead of numbers.

Also I think you have to use the ordinal dates with `mpl_finance candlestick_ohlc`:

```
    zip(mdates.date2num(AAPL.index.to_pydatetime()), AAPL['Open'], AAPL['High'], AAPL['Low'], AAPL['Close'], AAPL['Volume'])
```

Then use that in your `candlestick_ohlc` instead of `AAPL`.